# Windows: Find the location of recently created or downloaded files

Tags: windows, qt, fileinfo

How can I get information about recently created or downloaded files and directories at any location in the hard disk. I am developing the application in Qt on Windows.

Comment: Have a look at [QFileSystemWatcher](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfilesystemwatcher.html)

Comment: But it watches only specified paths and I want to get information about any file created at any path.

Comment: Qt can't help you here, this must be an OS/desktop specific function.

Comment: So, how can it be done in Windows?

Comment: Rephrase your question and adapt the tags, then you may get answers.